# DSE spark-submit failing with SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY, I do not have hadoop2 in cp

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying run the following java driver pgm in my local mac env, and i'm pretty sure I do not have hadoop2 in my class path and not sure why it still fails with shutdown-hook-priority error ?. Any insight will be of gr8 help, and I can run pyspark job with no exception

---

I am running dse 484 on my local and following is invocation

```
$SPARKBINFOLDER/dse spark-submit --master local[2] --class com.sample.driver.SampleLoader SampleLoader.jar $@
```

### Following is code snippet I am using

```
public class SampleLoader implements Serializable {

private transient SparkConf sconf;

private SampleLoader(SparkConf sconf) {
    this.sconf = sconf;
}

private void run() {
    //
       ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }
    //
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sconf);
    runSparkJob(jsc);
    jsc.stop();
}
private void runSparkJob(JavaSparkContext jsc) {

}

}
```

Following is classloader cp which I printed just before failed line of code ( JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sconf);)

```
########Printing the Classloader class path ........ /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/conf/ /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/lib/dse-core-4.8.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/lib/dse-hadoop-4.8.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/lib/dse-hive-4.8.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/lib/dse-search-4.8.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/lib/dse-spark-4.8.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/lib/dse-sqoop-4.8.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/conf/ /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/JavaEWAH-0.3.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/RoaringBitmap-0.4.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/ST4-4.0.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/activation-1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/akka-remote_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.4-spark.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/ant-1.9.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/asm-3.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/asm-4.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/asm-commons-3.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/asm-tree-3.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/breeze-macros_2.10-0.11.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/breeze_2.10-0.11.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/chill-java-0.5.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/chill_2.10-0.5.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/commons-net-2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/config-1.2.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/core-1.1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/httpclient-4.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jackson-annotations-2.3.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jackson-core-2.3.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.3.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jansi-1.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/javolution-5.5.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jets3t-0.7.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.14.v20131031.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-http-8.1.14.v20131031.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-io-8.1.14.v20131031.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-security-8.1.14.v20131031.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jline-2.10.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/joda-convert-1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/joda-time-2.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jodd-core-3.6.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jpam-1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/json-20090211.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jsr305-2.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jta-1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/jtransforms-2.4.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/junit-4.12.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/kryo-2.21.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/libfb303-0.9.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/minlog-1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/paranamer-2.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-column-1.6.0rc3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-common-1.6.0rc3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-encoding-1.6.0rc3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-format-2.2.0-rc1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-generator-1.6.0rc3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-hadoop-1.6.0rc3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.3.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/parquet-jackson-1.6.0rc3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/pmml-agent-1.1.15.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/pmml-model-1.1.15.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/pmml-schema-1.1.15.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0-spark.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/py4j-0.8.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/pyrolite-4.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/quasiquotes_2.10-2.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/scala-library-2.10.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/scalap-2.10.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/snappy-0.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-bagel_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10-1.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-catalyst_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-graphx_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-hive_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-launcher_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-mllib_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-network-common_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-repl_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-sql_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-unsafe_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spire-macros_2.10-0.7.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spire_2.10-0.7.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/stream-2.7.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/tachyon-0.6.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/tachyon-client-0.6.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/unused-1.0.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/velocity-1.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/xz-1.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-0.13-metastore-cassandra-connector-0.2.11.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-0.13.1-cassandra-connector-0.2.11.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-ant-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-beeline-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-cli-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-common-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-exec-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-hwi-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-jdbc-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-metastore-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-serde-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-service-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.20-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.20S-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-shims-0.23-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-shims-common-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/hive-shims-common-secure-0.13.1a.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/spark-hive-thriftserver_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/HdrHistogram-1.2.1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/antlr-3.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-asn1-ber-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-i18n-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-ldap-client-api-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-ldap-codec-core-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-ldap-codec-standalone-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-ldap-extras-codec-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-ldap-extras-codec-api-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-ldap-model-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-ldap-net-mina-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M24.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/commons-pool-1.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/guice-3.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/guice-multibindings-3.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/janino-2.6.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/java-uuid-generator-3.1.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/javax.inject-1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/jbcrypt-0.4d.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/jline-1.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/journalio-1.4.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/jsr305-2.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/kmip-1.7.1e.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/log4j-1.2.13.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/mina-core-2.0.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/reflections-0.9.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/dse/conf/ /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/ /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/conf/ /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/airline-0.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/ant-1.6.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/core-3.1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/ftplet-api-1.0.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/ftpserver-core-1.0.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/ftpserver-deprecated-1.0.0-M2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.18.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-examples-1.0.4.18.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.0.4.18.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.18.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-test-1.0.4.18.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/hadoop-tools-1.0.4.18.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/javax.inject-1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.7.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/mina-core-2.0.0-M5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/netty-3.9.8.Final.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/driver/lib/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/driver/lib/cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.7.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/driver/lib/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/driver/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/conf/ /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/tools/lib/stress.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.5.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/cassandra-all-2.1.12.1046.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/cassandra-clientutil-2.1.12.1046.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/cassandra-thrift-2.1.12.1046.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/fastutil-6.5.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/httpclient-4.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.4d.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/joda-time-1.6.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.33.dse.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.12.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.3.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar /Users/xxxxxx/cassandra/dse484/resources/hadoop/conf/
```

---

Following is Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getOrCreateLocalRootDirsImpl$2.apply(Utils.scala:653)
    at (JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at com.walmart.gis.spark.uber.ExtractCatalogItems.run(ExtractCatalogItems.java:60)
    at com.walmart.gis.spark.uber.ExtractCatalogItems.main(ExtractCatalogItems.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1584)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by setting scoped=provided on the spark dependency in the pom file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!--To fix the SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY error, add this line -->
    </dependency>
```

This forced Spark to use the Spark library included with DSE rather than the one packaged in my JAR file.